# obs resize output (source size) feature

Tags: obs

I use the **resize output (source size)** of the obs studio to fit the canvas size to windows. Unfortunately, sometimes this feature is grayed out and I cannot select it. See the below screenshot.

Why this happens and how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing; starting OBS in administrator-mode worked for me.